# how to read the data from an excel using spring batch

Tags: java, spring-batch

I would like to read the data from an excel sheet using spring batch. I have tried using rowMapper, however it did not work.

Comment: Use apache-poi for that.

Comment: use you this link (http://www.mkyong.com/spring-batch/spring-batch-example-csv-file-to-database/)

Comment: Thanks Bhargav... however I am looking 'how to read from excel sheet'

Comment: When I am trying to trigger the job, I am facing the below error.
====================================================================================== 
Cannot create inner bean '(inner 

bean)' of type [org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.xml.SimpleFlowFactoryBean] while setting bean property 'flow'; 

nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#8':

Answer (score 1):

Spring Batch has a related github repository called Spring Batch Extensions.  In it, we are slowly adding community contributed components like reader/writers for various systems.  One of the current pull requests is for an `ItemReader` for Excel.  While we're still working out the details on how to get it merged, you can still use it as is.  You can find it here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch-extensions/pull/2

Comment: using that code I faced the error
-------------------------------------------------------------------

 while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#8': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.springframework.batch.core.Step]: Could not convert constructor argument value of type [com.sun.proxy.$Proxy7] to required type [org.springframework.batch.core.Step]: Failed to convert value of type 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy7 implementing

Comment: I'd need to see your configuration

Comment: I implemented org.springframework.batch.core.Step and now it does not throw any error. Since I had some network issues I could not run the application. Will let you know once it is done.

Comment: Why did you implement step?  There's nothing within your questions that would need that.